# Can I use a tensorflowjs model in Python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

I am not really a tensorflow expert. I have been using it with provided models and code, played around a bit and am trying to get better with it.

I got a hold of a model that I'd like to play around with in the form of a tensorflowjs model (?). It is in the form a model.json with some "shard1ofX" files. I also got some JS code to accompany it which I kind of understand, but I am not really a JS developer and also would like to use the model and code not on the net but in a standalone application.

The model gets loaded like that in the JS implementation:

```
tf.loadGraphModel(path_to_model_json)
```

Is it somehow possible to read said model in the Python tensorflow implementation to use it? Googling around I found a ton of information about converting a model **TO** tensorflowjs format, but not the other way around.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The tfjs-converter project supports going from Javascript to Python. I haven't tested this but it looks like these flags should get the job done.

```
tfjs_converter --input_format tfjs_layers_model \
    --output_format keras_saved_model \
    /tmp/tensorflowjs_model \
    /tmp/keras_model
```

https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/blob/master/tfjs-converter/README.md#format-conversion-support-tables

Comment: That seems to work with a layered model. But I only have a Graph Model and it seems, there is no way back from that?

Comment: Looks like someone wrote a tool for converting a graph model to a saved model. Might for work you? 

https://github.com/patlevin/tfjs-to-tf

Comment: That looks is if it should do exactly what I want, but unfortunately it crashes with some rather cryptic error message `Error: Unsupported data type: 21`. I will have to look into it if this is a problem with my environment or versioning or with the model I have, but thanks a ton anyways!